# File reading as a resource

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have a "file" as a resource. I can only use `read()`, `write()` and `fstat()` it.  This file is a text file which I would like to parse.

Normally I use `fgets()` to read the text file line by line and parse it. How can I do this in this case?

```
FILE *fp;
char buffer[128];

fp = fopen( "/home/txtfile", "r" );
if (fp == NULL){
    perror("file missing");
}
while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
       //some code
}
```

How can I do the same with `read()` ?

Is this right?

```
int fd = open("/dev/file",O_RDONLY);
if (fd==-1) {
    printf("Failed to open file!!!\n");
}
while (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fd) != NULL) { 
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: I never thought to ask -- why can you only use read(), write(), and fstat()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your file is huge, if you're using read(), it would be easier to read in the entire file, then operate on the memory buffer, rather than in discrete chunks. That is, unless each line is of a fixed length.

I'd do something like this:

```
int rc;

int fd = open("data", O_RDONLY);  // open the file for reading
if (fd == -1) {
    // error
}

// to be thorough, do a stat() here to find how big to make the buffer
struct stat sb;
rc = fstat(fd, &sb);
if (rc == -1) {
    // error
}

char *buffer = calloc(1, sb.st_size);

int bytes_read = 0;
// read in entire file; each read() can be incomplete, hence why it's in a loop,
// and reading from/writing to increasing sections of the memory and file
while ((rc = read(fd, (buffer + bytes_read), (sb.st_size - bytes_read))) > 0) {
    if (rc == -1) {
        // error
    }

    bytes_read += rc;
}

close(fd);

// Now, to read it line-by-line...
char line[128]; // 128 is arbitrary
int pos = 0;
while ((rc = sscanf(buffer + pos, "%127[^\n]\n", line)) > 0) {
    pos += strlen(line) + 1;
    // do stuff with line
}

return 0;
```

Then you can operate on your memory buffer line-by-line by scanning for newlines, or using sscanf(). Also make sure to free() your buffer!

**Edit:** I've added some example code for using sscanf() to handle your buffer. If you know the format of the lines (you say you're parsing them) you might be able to make better use of sscanf() by using the format specifiers. All of this is untested, by the way.

Comment: I dont want to read the entire file in the first read. I want to read it line by line... or perhaps a big buffer for the entire file and then scan it line by line into a lower buffer. how can I do this?

Comment: I get a segmentation fault at sscanf() can u pls check?

Comment: actually although here is data in buffer, "line" seems empty :(

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
int fd = open("/dev/file",O_RDONLY);
ssize_t res = 0;
while((res = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    //some code
}
if (res < 0) {
    //handle error
} else{
   //close fd
}
```

Comment: `ssize_t`, not `size_t`.  I'll assume that's just a typo.  For the record and the asker, `ssize_t` is signed so that it can return `-1` on error; `size_t` is signed so it can return any size.

Comment: @Kevin: Seems you made a typo yourself... `size_t` is _unsigned_, and can return any _positive_ size. :)

Comment: It appears I did. :)  ah, well. Second "signed"->"unsigned".  As for "positive", "size" can't be negative, so I think it's implied.  And technically, it's any *nonnegative* size, as size *can* be zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this right?

No.

[read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) is a system call that operates on a Unix file descriptor, not a stdio `FILE*`.  Other than that, it works by reading data from the file and putting it in the buffer you supply.

```
int fd = open("/dev/file",O_RDONLY);
if (fd==-1) 
{
    printf("Failed to open file!!!\n");
}
else
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    while (bytesRead > 0) 
    { 
        // do something with the buffer
        bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    }
    if (bytesRead == -1)
    {
        // error
    }
    // bytesRead == 0 => end of file

}
```